# How to get a part of a string from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have this table row

```
id  |  text

1   |  {"category_layout":"","image":"images\/icon-48-info.png"}
```

How can I get only the image path from the text inside the brackets?

What I need is only this: images/icon-48-info.png
(Note that there are 2 slashes in the text \ / while I need only one /

**EDIT**:    Actually it is very simple, and I found a nice solution:

```
$json = $row->text;
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->{'image'};
```

No need for regexp or anything else.

Comment: It appears you're storing that column in JSON. There might be a way to do it with regex, but it will be very costly. I recommend doing this in your server side language (example json_decode in PHP) instead.

Comment: Yes, it's much cheaper to just `SELECT` it based on the id then hand it away from your database.

Comment: ...Alternately store the raw data, and build the JSON as required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is very simple, and I found a nice solution:

```
$json = $row->text;
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->{'image'};?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the string functions [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), try it using the [Regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) or [Substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)